# Spring missing query parameters exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public DtoUser getUserById( @PathParam("id")  @PathVariable("id") @RequestParam Long id) {
    return adminService.getUserById(id);
}
```

and this code:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
        public ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(
                HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
            return error_with_my_info;
    }

    @Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(
        MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {{
        return error_with_my_info;
    }
...
}
```

The problem is that when I send a request WITHOUT a parameter, it is **handleHttpMessageNotReadable** that is called, not **handleMissingServletRequestParameter**.
Why is that?
Can other API endpoints affect this behaviour, like having a PUT request handler with the same endpoint?
How can I make it so that **handleMissingServletRequestParameter**?

Comment: why do you have `@PathParam("id")`  `@PathVariable("id")` `@RequestParam`, you don't need all three. PathParam and PathVariable are basically the same. Request params are for request parameters. This is probably your problem.

Comment: pathparam is for parameters in the path. http://localhost:8080/foo (the foo part is the parameter). Requestparam is for request parameters http://localhost:8080?id=foo

Answer (score 1):

Improvised :

```
@GetMapping(value = "/users")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public DtoUser getUserById(  @RequestParam(value="id" , required=true)Long id) {
    return adminService.getUserById(id);
}
```

localhost:8080?id=test
now if you dont pass id it will give you handleMissingServletRequestParameter.